# jQuery animate() element height and accounting for dynamic content

Tags: jquery

When a section has sub sections, the master sections height is set for all the sub sections when open, but they collapse *on page load*.

I'm not the best at math (dyscalculia), and am I little puzzled on how I can dynamically account for what sub menus are open or closed, and keeping the master blocks height relative to them.

https://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/2ksy68zq/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var linkblocks = $(".entry-content").children("#links-toggle-block");
    var colHeight = 70;
    linkblocks.each(function(id) {
        var blk = $(this);
        var subBlocks = blk.children("#links-sub-block");
        var blkHeight = blk.outerHeight();
        var header = blk.find(".links-toggle-header").first();
          if(!(blk.hasClass("toggleBlk"))) {
              blk.css({"height": colHeight+"px"}).addClass("toggleBlk");
              header.find(".links-icon").html("expand_more");
          }
          header.click(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              if(blk.hasClass("toggleBlk")) {
                  blk.animate({"height": blkHeight+"px"}).removeClass("toggleBlk");
                  header.find(".links-icon").html("expand_less");
              } else {
                  blk.animate({"height": colHeight+"px"}).addClass("toggleBlk");
                  header.find(".links-icon").html("expand_more");
              }
          });
          if(subBlocks.length > 0)
            subBlocks.each(function(id) {
                var sub = $(this);
                var subHeight = sub.outerHeight();
                var subHead = sub.find(".links-sub-header").first();
                if(!(sub.hasClass("toggleSub"))) {
                    sub.css({"height": colHeight+"px"}).addClass("toggleSub");
                    subHead.find(".links-icon").html("expand_more");
                }
                subHead.click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if(sub.hasClass("toggleSub")) {
                        sub.animate({"height": subHeight+"px"}).removeClass("toggleSub");
                        subHead.find(".links-icon").html("expand_less");
                    } else {
                        sub.animate({"height": colHeight+"px"}).addClass("toggleSub");
                        subHead.find(".links-icon").html("expand_more");
                    }
                });
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, without the need to calculate too much.

Basically I just grab the heights of the internal content minus headers

```
blkSubHeight = (blkSubHeight + (subHeight - colHeight));
```

And than dynamically switch from hidden visibility to visible.

I think this is the best way, though I may be wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/sqgr0beL/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var linkblocks = $(".entry-content").children("#links-toggle-block");
    var colHeight = 70;
    linkblocks.each(function(id) {
        var blk = $(this);
        var blkSubHeight = 0;
        var subBlocks = blk.children("#links-sub-block");
        var blkHeight = blk.outerHeight();
        var header = blk.find(".links-toggle-header").first();
          if(!(blk.hasClass("toggleBlk"))) {
              blk.css({"height": colHeight+"px"}).addClass("toggleBlk");
              header.find(".links-icon").html("expand_more");
          }
          header.click(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              if(blk.hasClass("toggleBlk")) {
                    if(subBlocks.length > 0) {
                    blk.animate({"height": blkHeight - blkSubHeight+"px"})
                         .removeClass("toggleBlk");
                  } else {
                    blk.animate({"height": blkHeight+"px"})
                       .removeClass("toggleBlk");
                  }
                  header.find(".links-icon").html("expand_less");
              } else {
                    if(subBlocks.length > 0) {
                        blk.css({"overflow": "hidden"});
                  }
                  blk.animate({"height": colHeight+"px"})
                     .addClass("toggleBlk");
                  header.find(".links-icon").html("expand_more");
              }
          });
          if(subBlocks.length > 0)
            subBlocks.each(function(id) {
                var sub = $(this);
                var subHeight = sub.outerHeight();
                blkSubHeight = (blkSubHeight + (subHeight - colHeight));
                var subHead = sub.find(".links-sub-header").first();
                if(!(sub.hasClass("toggleSub"))) {
                    sub.css({"height": colHeight+"px"}).addClass("toggleSub");
                    subHead.find(".links-icon").html("expand_more");
                }
                subHead.click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    blk.css({"overflow": "visible", "height": "auto"});
                    if(sub.hasClass("toggleSub")) {
                        sub.animate({"height": subHeight+"px"})
                           .removeClass("toggleSub");
                        subHead.find(".links-icon").html("expand_less");
                    } else {
                        sub.animate({"height": colHeight+"px"})
                           .addClass("toggleSub");
                        subHead.find(".links-icon").html("expand_more");
                    }
                });
            });
    });
});
```